# Android: EditText in CustomView not behaving as expected when touched

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I have a CustomView which contains a LinearLayout that holds an EditText & another custom view element. However, when I run my app and touch the EditText it does not behave as expected (doesn't appear to receive focus & the soft keyboard doesn't open). I've tried setting duplicateParentState="true" on both the EditText & the LinearLayout. I also attached an onTouchEventListener to the EditText that calls a simple toast & the toast did show up.

Here's the code for my CustomView.

form_field.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_rounded_borders">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#2d6169"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@color/transparent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.example.app.ValidationIcon
            android:id="@+id/validation_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

FormField.java

```java
package com.example.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FormField extends LinearLayout {

    private EditText editText;
    private ValidationIcon validationIcon;

    private Integer fieldInputType;
    private String fieldInputHint;

    public FormField(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public FormField(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
    {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        TypedArray attrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.FormField, 0, 0);

        fieldInputType = attrs.getInt(
                R.styleable.FormField_fieldInputType,
                InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL
        );
        fieldInputHint = attrs.getString(
            R.styleable.FormField_fieldInputHint
        );

        attrs.recycle();

        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.form_field, this);

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        editText.setInputType(fieldInputType);
        editText.setHint(fieldInputHint);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        validationIcon = (ValidationIcon)findViewById(R.id.validation_icon);
        validationIcon.setValid(true);

        ArrayList<View> touchables = new ArrayList<View>();
        touchables.add(this);
        touchables.add(editText);

        addTouchables(touchables);
    }

    public FormField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

}
```

registration_layout.xml

```xml
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/account_details"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.example.app.FormField
            android:id="@+id/name_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:fieldInputHint="@string/name_field_hint" />

        <com.example.app.FormField
            android:id="@+id/email_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:fieldInputHint="@string/email_field_hint" />

        <com.example.app.FormField
            android:id="@+id/password_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:fieldInputHint="@string/password_field_hint" />

        <com.example.app.FormField
            android:id="@+id/re_password_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:fieldInputHint="@string/re_password_field_hint" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Min SDK Version is set at 14, target is set at 20. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I got this logcat message today while testing long presses on my FormFields.

```
W/TextView﹕ TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.
```

I double checked my code and the EditText element is only ever cast as an EditText. If the EditText is being cast to a TextView that would explain my original issues but now I'm confused as to why or how it was cast as a TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are extending LinearLayout but never using it in your layout.  From what you've posted, you aren't using the FormField at all and the only custom View I see is the ValidationIcon view.  So hooking the touch events into EditText and ValidationIcon aren't occurring because you aren't using FormField in your layout.xml.

Rather than extending LinearLayout, why not just use the predefined methods and attributes to handle the behaviour you are trying to achieve.  For example, displaying keyboard, requesting focus, and displaying hint:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    **android:inputType="text"**
    **android:hint="@styleable/FormField_fieldInputHint"**
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#2d6169"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="@color/transparent" />
```

The keyboard should display when the edit text receives focus, if not you could programmatically do this by requesting focus and handling the IME manager call.  For example, from the Activity/Fragment:

```
//call this from onViewCreated to grab focus and begin the flow
editText.requestFocus();
//set focus listener to handle keyboard display
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
          if (!hasFocus) {
              InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
              imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
     } else {
              InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
              imm.showSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
     }
});
```

Comment: I've updated my original question with some new information & my registration_layout.xml so you can see how I'm using the FormField element.

Comment: yes, this makes much more sense now.  Are you certain that it is calling the second constructor?  Maybe test by moving your custom code to a separate method and calling that in each constructor?

Comment: I got it working! It was a combination of using an init method with all three constructors as you said and also changing my _fieldInputType_ default from `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL` to `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure have not been setting `inputType:'none'` or '0X000000'

Answer (score 0):

- > [image]

use this code for custom Edittext with title

custom_view.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:foregroundGravity="right"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/search_closed_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="right">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/intel"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:text="textview"
                android:textColor="@color/title_color"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_txtbg"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/intel"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:paddingStart="24dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/txt_hint"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_nev"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_add_patient"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
    </FrameLayout>
```

CustomEditText.kt

```
        package com.mdppractice.custom
    
    import android.content.Context
    import android.text.InputType
    import android.util.AttributeSet
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.widget.EditText
    import android.widget.FrameLayout
    import android.widget.TextView
    import com.mdppractice.R
    
    
    class CustomEditText(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet,
    ) : FrameLayout(context, attrs) {
    
        private var txt_title: TextView
        private var edt_text: EditText
    
        init {
            LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_view, this, true)
            txt_title = findViewById(R.id.txt_title)
            edt_text = findViewById(R.id.edt_text)
    
    
            val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText)
            txt_title.text = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_title)
            edt_text.hint = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hint)
    
            when(a.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_inputType)) {
                "number" -> edt_text.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
                "textCapSentences" -> edt_text.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES
                "text" -> edt_text.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
            }
    
            a.recycle()
    
        }
    
        fun setmInputType(type: Int) {
            edt_text.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
            setmInputType(type)
        }
    
        fun setTitle(title: Int) {
            txt_title.setText(title)
        }
    
        fun set_Text(title: Int) {
            edt_text.setText(title)
        }
    
        fun getTitle(): String {
            return txt_title.text.toString()
        }
    
        fun get_Text(): String {
            return edt_text.text.toString()
        }
    
    
    }
```

main/../attr.xml

```
  <declare-styleable name="CustomEditText">
    <attr name="title" format="string"/>
    <attr name="onCenter" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="hint" format="string"/>
    <attr name="maxLength" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="inputType" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

@drawable/edit_txtbg

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/button_bg_border" />
            <padding android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/button_bg" />
        
        </shape>
```

- > use in layout

  ```
                <com.mdppractice.custom.CustomEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_custom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:title="Patient ID/Phone"
                android:autofillHints="@string/verified"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:hint="Please enter name"
                app:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:textColor="@color/title_color"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
  ```

thanks you